# Firebase: Prevent clientside callback execution if write permission is denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have some validation rules set up that e.g. wont allow messages in chat that are longer than 300 characters.

The rule works fine but (AFAIK) firebase likes to optimise the experience a lot which lead to them executing callbacks like "child_added" before the server tells us that it was ok.

This makes the message appear in the chat but not arrive on the server leaving us in an unsynced state.

Is there a way to prevent the callback from being fired until the server said its ok?

The only workaround I see now is catching the permission denied event and removing the message again. This will however not result in an experience as clean as it could be (not adding message to chat at all compared to having it appear and then shortly after disapear)

Comment: I left a short answer of how Firebase security rules validation works. Without seeing the minimal code that reproduces the problem, this is the best I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server-side security rules reject your write operation, the Firebase client fires events to reconcile the local app. For example: if you added a new child (`child_added`), the client will fire a `child_removed` once it knows the server rejected the operation.

As long as your app handles all `child_*` events correctly, the UI can be kept properly up to date.

Comment: Oh I see. That makes a lot of sense. So basicly theres not really a way to avoid adding it in the first place? I guess I could add the message to a queue in the child_added event and have the "adding" job be executed a bit delayed, hoping to have the child_removed event fired before the delay ends. If so then I reject the job. Seems dirty though. Any thoughts?

Comment: Typically your client-side code should already be written so that you don't (or at least seldom) post data that will be rejected. The easiest way is to just do what the API steers towards: show the update locally, the update if it gets rejected.

Comment: Youre right. I can just validate clientside. I will go and get another coffee now...